# Shorthand if with continue

Tags: php, syntax, conditional-operator, continue

I really like using PHP's shorthand `if`, but when trying to use it with a `continue` command, my IDE marks it as an error (Syntax error, unexpected `continue`). Trying to figure out why, I ran it in my browser (with the code bellow), but it doesn't give me any error.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo 'test<br /><br />';

foreach(range(1,10) as $i) {
    $i == '6' ? continue : '';
    echo $i.'<br />';
}
?>
```

This just doesn't output anything. However, if I comment out the line with the `continue` in it, it works as expected.

What exaclty am I missing here?

Comment: The ternary operator is not a "shorthand if"! It does conditional *assignment*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use ternary operator to do this.

Change your line by the following:

```
if ($i == 6) continue ;
```

Answer (score 2):

This short hand notation happens during you set a variable. So what you would do then is

```
$i = continue;
```

I guess then you could trigger the continue this way:

```
$i();
```

But this is not what you want.

Also you should not modify the iterator within the loop!

So just use

```
if ($whatever) continue;
```